# Find middle digit in an integer in Java

Tags: java, performance

I have an integer in java "1234567" and my program finds middle digit in a set of integer, is there more optimized way than below code?. Recently asked in java interview.

What I have done is first find no of digits, first, last and middle indexes. Then find middle digit again iterating on same integer. Please advice some optimization.

```
int a1 = 1234567;
int a = a1;

// calculate length
int noOfDigits = 0;
while(a!=0)
{
   a = a/10;
   noOfDigits++;
}

int first = 0;
int last = noOfDigits-1;
int middle = (first+last)/2;

boolean midExists = ((a1%2)==1);
System.out.println(" digits: "+a1);
System.out.println(" no of digits "+noOfDigits);
System.out.println(" first "+first);
System.out.println(" last " + last);

if(midExists)
{
   System.out.println(" middle " + middle);
   int i = last;
   int middleDigit = 0;
   a = a1;
   while(i != middle)
   {
     a = (a / 10);
     middleDigit = (a%10);
     i--;
   }
   System.out.println("middle digit: " + middleDigit);
 }
 else
   System.out.println(" Mid not Exists.. ");
```

Program Output:

```
digits: 1234567
no of digits 7
first 0
last 6
middle 3
middle digit: 4
```

Comment: what about the char at length/2-1??

Comment: int numberOfDigits = String.valueOf(a1).length(); instead of the while loop

Comment: I would convert to String and get the middle one of the string.

Comment: I have to do that without using language methods like length(), or converting it to array or string

Comment: side note: you don't need `first`. `int middle = last/2;`

Comment: @WaqasMahmood For the record: I reworded the first paragraph, to point out the one trick that is possible to simplify your code. But that only works in case you are allowed to use Math.log10() for this assignment.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for such explanatory answers :) Understood other things than the main requirement to my question :) Apology for not mentioning that language methods are not allowed :)

Comment: You are very welcome. And hey, you reached 100 today. Congratulations ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also do this in one pass. Idea is that first store the `integer` in the another variable. Then move two digits to the left in one `integer` while only one digit in the another one.

```
int a1 = 1234567;  
int a2 = a1;
int flag=0;

while(a2>0)
{
    a2/=10;               //Moves to the left by one digit
    if(a2==0)             //If there are odd no. of digits
    {
        flag=1;
        break;
    }
    a2/=10;               //Moves to the left by one digit
    a1/=10;               //Moves to the left by one digit
}
System.out.print(flag!=1?"No Mid Exists":a1%10);
```

Comment: interesting approach.

Comment: Now that is the answer :) Thanks @Sanket Makani

Comment: you got a `=` too much in the last line

Comment: Oh yes, @XtremeBaumer . That was the mistake,Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Agreed. Always good to see that other people have that special idea that makes this site so valuable! Have my vote, too!

Comment: Great! It's the approach used to find the middle of a linked list in one pass.

Answer (score 8):

Your "math" is working correctly. The one thing you can: compute the **length** (number of digits) within your number **upfront**, to avoid "iterating" the number twice - so you can determine if that number of digits is even or odd **without** "iterating" the number:

```
int n = 1234;
int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
```

should give you 4 for 1234, and 5 for 12345.

But beyond that: you can express information in different ways. For example: you can turn an *int* value into a string.

```
String asStr = Integer.toString(123456);
```

And now: you can easily check the **length** of that string; and you can directly access the corresponding character!

The only thing to keep in mind: characters representing numbers like '1', '2', ... have **different** numerical values as int 1, 2, ... (see an ASCII table; as '1' is 49 when regarding its numerical value)!

Comment: `System.out.println(str.charAt(str.length() / 2));` will print the correct value i.e. 4 in this case

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have to do that without using language methods like length(), or converting it to array or string

Comment: @WaqasMahmood then you should state that in your question

Comment: @GhostCat since he is not allowed to use an array, i doubt he is allowed to use a list as they are pretty equal

Answer (score 4):

this answer has less code, but wouldn't take much in performance i think:

```
int a1 = 12334;
int a = a1;
int middle = 0;
int noOfDigits = 0;

while (a1 != 0) {
    a1 = a1 / 10;
    noOfDigits++;
}
if (noOfDigits % 2 == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (noOfDigits / 2) + 1; i++) {
        middle = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    System.out.println(middle);
} else {
    System.out.println("No mid existing");
}
```

Comment: `a1=1233` . Does middle exist in this? Your code prints `Yes`.

Comment: yeah not the best check. but the same as op uses

Comment: noOfDigits length check is correct to take a decision on mid exists or not as @GhostCat posted..

Comment: Correct. And I reworked my answer to put up a check that gives you the **correct** number of digits within your number ;-)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer And good that you started your own answer; that point is valid ... you got my vote.

Comment: @GhostCat not sure, but i think `Math` operations are not allowed either. otherwise good answer from you

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Nobody prevents you from computing log10 manually. Cough cough. Math.log10 just does some computations; I am sure one can compute that without relying on any Math.builtin-thing.

Comment: surely. as op stated: `I have to do that without using language methods like length(), or converting it to array or string` i think this covers the builtin methods as length() is also a builtin method

Comment: So is println() ;-) ... and if/while are *language* elements, too. Reminds me on my days in university, when we were supposed to solve problems using the **while** language - which only had *one* construct - a while (bool) loop. That was *fun* ...

Comment: okay, point for you, then op has to decide for him what he uses

Answer (score 1):

Using only math

```
int num = 123406789;
int countDigits = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log10(num));
int midIndex = (int)Math.ceil(countDigits/2);
int x = num / (int)Math.pow(10, midIndex);
int middleDigit = x % 10;
System.out.println(middleDigit);
```

Comment: Apologies.. I forgot to mention that in my question, language methods are not allowed :)